# How to get the value of a taxonomy term from entity reference using a token?

Tags: 8, hooks, tokens

We have an Entity reference field on `Basic Page` content type that is set to `Articles`. The `Articles` content type has a field, `field_category` that is a taxonomy term.

What is the correct token to get the value of the `field_category`?

Basic Page:

- `field_articles` -> entity reference to `Article` content type.

Article page:

- `field_category` -> taxonomy term field.

Goal:

- Return the `field_category` label from the `Article` node that is set on the `Basic Page`

Example:

Basic Page -> `page1(nid=0)`

1. `field_articles` = articlePage1 `(target_id = 1)`

Article page -> `ArticlePage1 (nid = 1)`

1. `field_category` = `Cloud` (tid = 10)

Token should return `Cloud` for `page1`.

We tried the following but it didn't work.

```
[node:field_articles:entity:field_category]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try use hook_tokens

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_tokens().
     */
    function mymodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, \Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
$replacements = array();
// $type is token type
      if ($type == 'node' && !empty($data['node'])) {
        foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      // to do
        $replacements[$original] ='xxx';
       }
      }
      return $replacements;
    }
```

See more api [hook_tokens()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_tokens/8.2.x)

Comment: the custom token has been working as expected.